# Expected response code "250" but got empty code

Tags: laravel

I have this problem when I want to forget my password, I use the breeze authentication to set up my login and register and I create an account in mailtrap so I can get the email inbox

I set up the configuration to my .env file like this

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp     
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io     
MAIL_PORT=2525     
MAIL_USERNAME=6ef08e9eb5cfd4     
MAIL_PASSWORD=0c593bdbaed36f     
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

but when I wanted to reset my password on the website I get this error:

> Expected the response code "250" but got an empty code.

I am using Laravel 9 I did change the port but still didn't work.

Comment: Share minimal reproducible example to understand the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If .env variables are good to go then clear config cache of system.

we solved this problem by clearing Laravel's configuration cache

```
php artisan config:clear
```

> or

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Also please check email from address is set or not during sending mail. If not then add any dummy email like `admin@example.com` for fire a email.

I hope you will get success by doing this trick.